# rename all files in one directory based on a matching substring from files in another directory

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to rename all files in one directory based on a matching substring of the current filename to the full filename of the files in the other directory. For example I have two directories with 1200 files similar to the following example where I want the second directory of files to be renamed to the full filename based on the unique matching ID/substring:

```
Directory 1:
ABC_MA123.bed
EFG_MA124.bed
XYZ_MA125.bed

Directory 2:
MA123.bed
MA124.bed
MA125.bed
```

Desired result:

```
Directory 2:
ABC_MA123.bed
EFG_MA124.bed
XYZ_MA125.bed
```

Is there an easy way to do this with a bash/awk script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure each file in directory 2 has exactly one match in directory 1?

You could do something like this, assuming the directories are /tmp/1 and /tmp/2:

```
(cd /tmp/2; ls -1) | 
(cd /tmp/1; while read f2; do f1=(/tmp/1/*$f2); echo mv $f2 ${f1##*/}; done)
```

For each file in directory 2, find a file in directory 1 with the same suffix, then rename the file in directory 2 to the name of the matching file in directory 1. The `${f1##*/}` strips the path off of `f1`.

Comment: Awesome this worked perfectly, thanks! Each file does have exactly one match in the second of the two directories

Comment: I forgot to mention, I wrote it so it echos the mv commands instead of executing them... I didn't want it to do the wrong thing and scramble your files. You probably figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming filenames in dir2 are substrings of filenames in dir1, simple globbing should work:

```
d1="/full/path/to/dir1"
d2="/full/path/to/dir2"

cd "$d2"
for f2 in *; do
    f1=("$d1"/*"$f2"*)
    if [[ ${#f1[@]} != 1 ]]; then
        printf "ERROR: multiple matches: %s\n" "$f2" 1>&2
    elif [[ ! -f $f1 ]]; then
        printf "ERROR: no match: %s\n" "$f2" 1>&2
    else
        new="${f1##*/}" # strip to bare filename
        if [[ $f2 == $new ]]; then
            printf "WARNING: no change: %s\n" "$f2" 1>&2
        elif [[ -f $new ]]; then
            printf "ERROR: exists: %s\n" "$new" 1>&2
        else
            mv "$f2" "${f1##*/}"
        fi
    fi
done
```